# how to get parent array index from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $arr.

when I print this it shows the results as follows.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgarden-Control Type
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgarden-Depth
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgarden-Height
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgarden-Load Type
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgarden-Machine Type
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgarden-Type
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgarden-Width
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => computer & ele
            [label] => 
            [singular_label] => 
            [hierarchical] => 1
            [show_ui] => 1
            [query_var] => 1
            [rewrite] => 1
            [rewrite_slug] => 
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [search_items] => 
                    [popular_items] => 
                    [all_items] => 
                    [parent_item] => 
                    [parent_item_colon] => 
                    [edit_item] => 
                    [update_item] => 
                    [add_new_item] => 
                    [new_item_name] => 
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => 
                    [add_or_remove_items] => 
                    [choose_from_most_used] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => computer
            [label] => 
            [singular_label] => 
            [hierarchical] => 1
            [show_ui] => 1
            [query_var] => 1
            [rewrite] => 1
            [rewrite_slug] => 
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [search_items] => 
                    [popular_items] => 
                    [all_items] => 
                    [parent_item] => 
                    [parent_item_colon] => 
                    [edit_item] => 
                    [update_item] => 
                    [add_new_item] => 
                    [new_item_name] => 
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => 
                    [add_or_remove_items] => 
                    [choose_from_most_used] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgardenairconditioner-Type
            [label] => 
            [singular_label] => 
            [hierarchical] => 1
            [show_ui] => 1
            [query_var] => 1
            [rewrite] => 1
            [rewrite_slug] => 
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [search_items] => 
                    [popular_items] => 
                    [all_items] => 
                    [parent_item] => 
                    [parent_item_colon] => 
                    [edit_item] => 
                    [update_item] => 
                    [add_new_item] => 
                    [new_item_name] => 
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => 
                    [add_or_remove_items] => 
                    [choose_from_most_used] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => homeandgardendishwasher-Control Type
            [label] => 
            [singular_label] => 
            [hierarchical] => 1
            [show_ui] => 1
            [query_var] => 1
            [rewrite] => 1
            [rewrite_slug] => 
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [search_items] => 
                    [popular_items] => 
                    [all_items] => 
                    [parent_item] => 
                    [parent_item_colon] => 
                    [edit_item] => 
                    [update_item] => 
                    [add_new_item] => 
                    [new_item_name] => 
                    [separate_items_with_commas] => 
                    [add_or_remove_items] => 
                    [choose_from_most_used] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product
                )

        )
)
```

and I have a variable $categ.For example $categ = "**homeandgardenairconditioner-Type**"
then I want to know the index of the parent array whose "**name**" is "**homeandgardenairconditioner-Type**"

i.e --- o/p should be 9

how to get this index. Please help me

Thanks

Comment: @PLB I don't know how to traverse in this array so that first I check it's name and then get it's parent array index that's why I am asking.Thanks

Comment: Is it already defined that your values will be located in the first dimension of the array ? Or it should be used to find values in `$array[$i][$j][$k][$etc]` ?

Comment: @Frederik.L I have 'name' .Can you write your code which will work?Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
function getIndex($name, $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value) && $value['name'] == $name)
              return $key;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `$index = array_search( $value, array_column( $array, 'name' ) );`
I think this work too .