# Find parents key in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a method to find all parents of a multidimensional PHP array 
I have this following array:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                    [ab] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ab.jpg
                        )

                    [0] => abc.jpg
                )

            [b] => Array
                (
                    [ba] => Array
                        (
                            [bab] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => abc.jpg
                                )

                            [bac] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => abd.jpg
                                )

                            [0] => ade.jpg
                        )

                )

            [c] => Array
                (
                    [cb] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => abf.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to find Parents by key, for example,
To find all parents of key: 'bac'

It should return:

```
files->b->ba->bac
```

Any suggestion or example? Help will be much appriciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/211213-recursively-search-a-multidimensional-array-and-return-all-parents/   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607635/how-to-get-parent-array-index-from-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: Take a look at some search algorithm such as binary search. Just out of sheer curiosity... What happens when I search for the parents of the key 0?

Answer (score 1):

Function:

```
function array_search_key_recursive($key, array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $i => $child) {
        if ($i === $key) {
            return $i;
        }
        if (!is_array($child)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (false !== $j = array_search_key_recursive($key, $child)) {
            return "{$i}->{$j}";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Test:
http://ideone.com/T2Obqg