# Outer Array Index

Tags: arrays, yii2

Array looks like below :

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [memberid] => 5203
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [memberid] => 494
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [memberid] => 1053
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [memberid] => 1081
            )
    )
```

How can i find-out the outer array index (such as 0,1,2) using inner array.

Comment: Do you want to all index or just one. If you iterate above array using foreach loop you have that key. Missing usecase.

Comment: I want to know the outer array index of the member which i am choosing. What I mean is, if i am choosing the member with member id 1081, i wanna display the index 3. Help please

Comment: and how you choose member id **1081** ? By means of index or loop. How do you reach id **1081**? [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607635/how-to-get-parent-array-index-from-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the outer array, and save the key if the current inner array value matches like this:

```
$outerKey = null;
foreach($outerArray as $key => $member){
    if($member['memberid'] == 1081){
        $outerKey = $key;
        break;
    }
}
echo $outerKey; // it will print 3
```